# Framer-motion Animation With Typescript: ScrollY doesn't find .current

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, framer-motion

I'm trying to create an animation that hides the menu when the user scrolls down and when the user returns to the top the menu appears.

Everything works, but the problem comes when I try to give to the scrollY property  that gives the `useScroll` hook a type.

This is the code that I could not find the way to implement the type.

```
 const { scrollY } = useScroll();
 const [isScrolling, setScrolling] = useState<boolean>(false);

 const handleScroll = () => {
  if (scrollY?.current < scrollY?.prev) setScrolling(false);
  if (scrollY?.current > 100 && scrollY?.current > scrollY?.prev) setScrolling(true);
 };

useEffect(() => {
  return scrollY.onChange(() => handleScroll());
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution!

Reading the documentation framer, I saw that they updated the way to get the value of the previous and current scroll.

`scrollY.get()` -> Current

`scrollY.getPrevious()` -> Previous

```
 const { scrollY } = useScroll();
 const [isScrolling, setScrolling] = useState<boolean>(false);

 const handleScroll = () => {
  if (scrollY.get() < scrollY.getPrevious()) setScrolling(false);
  if (scrollY.get() > 100 && scrollY.get() > scrollY.getPrevious()) setScrolling(true);
 };

 useEffect(() => {
  return scrollY.onChange(() => handleScroll());
 });
```